Laravel sail integrate oracle-instantclient into Dockerfile
I have exported the laravel sail docker file and trying to run the following lines:
...

RUN  wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2113000/oracle-instantclient-basic-21.13.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm \
    && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2113000/oracle-instantclient-sqlplus-21.13.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm \
    && wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/2113000/oracle-instantclient-devel-21.13.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm \
    && alien -i oracle-instantclient-basic-21.13.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm \
    && alien -i oracle-instantclient-sqlplus-21.13.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm \
    && alien -i oracle-instantclient-devel-21.13.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm

...

If I remove the 2 lines about sqlplus I can build the container no problem, but with those 2 lines I get the following error:
Unpacking of 'oracle-instantclient-sqlplus-21.13.0.0.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm' failed at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package/Rpm.pm line 168.

Any clues why this could be happening? (I confirmed that the files are downloaded and are intact)
